# How to find the length of substring of a palindrome which itself is not a palindrome?

Tags: java, string, palindrome, substring

I have written this code but it shows Time Limit Exceeded. How can I make this fast?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Palin{
  public static void main(String ar[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = input.next();
    for(int i = 1 ;i < s.length() ; i++){
        if(!(s.substring(0,i).equals(new StringBuilder(s.substring(0,i)).reverse().toString()))){
            System.out.print(s.substring(0,i).length());
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why do you need a program for this? the simplest answer is n-1
if "abcdcba" is palindrome then remove the last char - "abcdcb" - and you get a non palindrome substring. isn't it. or is your question different. post test case examples

Comment: what if input string is "abc"(correct output = 3) or "aaa"(correct output=1) ?

Comment: what if input string is "abc"(correct output = 3) or "aaa"(correct output=1) ? @ManasMarthi

Answer (score 0):

See this code
It has methods to find

1. All possible substrings of various lengths
2. Longest Non Palindrome substring
3. Longest Palindrome substring (using lambdas)

The third one was provided to show how to solve the problem using lambdas
Junit test cases follow at the bottom

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.HashSet;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Set;
 import java.util.stream.Collector;
 import java.util.stream.Collectors;

 public class MyStrings {

    private String s;
    public MyStrings(String s) {
        super();
        if(s==null||s.trim().length()==0) s="";
        this.s = s;
    }

    public Set<String> getAllSubStrings() {

        Set<String> list=new HashSet();
        for (int i=0, m=s.length()-1,n=m+1 ;i<=m;i++) {
            for (int j=i+1;j<=n;j++)
                list.add(s.substring(i, j));
        }
        return list;
    }

    public String getLongestPalindromeSubstr(boolean excludeOriginal) {
        Set<String> subs = this.getAllSubStrings();

        //if original string to be not considered then remove it from the set
        if (excludeOriginal)
            subs.remove(s);

        if(s.isEmpty()) 
            return "";

        return subs.stream()
        .filter(s-> new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString().equals(s))
        .sorted((s1,s2)-> {//sorted in descending order of string length
            if (s1.length()<s2.length()) return 1;
            if (s1.length()==s2.length()) return 0;
            return -1;
        }) 
        .findFirst()
        .get(); //return the biggest palindrome substring

        /*
        Set<String> subs =this.getAllSubStrings();
        System.out.println(subs);

        List<String> palindromSubStrings  = subs.stream()
        .filter(s->  new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString().equals(s))
        .sorted((s1,s2)-> {
            //System.out.println("comparing ["+s1+"],["+s2+"]");
            if (s1.length()<s2.length()) return 1;
            if (s1.length()==s2.length()) return 0;
            return -1;
        }) //sorted in descending order
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println("palindromSubStrings"+palindromSubStrings);
        return palindromSubStrings.stream().
        findFirst().get();
        */

    }
    public String getLongestNonPalindromeSubstr(boolean excludeOriginal) {
        Set<String> subs =this.getAllSubStrings();
        Set<String> nonPalindromes = new HashSet();
        for (String str:subs) {
            if (! new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString().equals(str))
                nonPalindromes.add(str); //remove 
        }
        //if original string to be not considered then remove it from the set
        if (excludeOriginal)
            nonPalindromes.remove(s);
        System.out.println("Non Palindromes with parent excluded="+excludeOriginal+" is "+nonPalindromes);
        if (nonPalindromes.isEmpty())return "";
        String longest="";
        for (String str:nonPalindromes)
            if(str.length()>=longest.length()) longest=str;

        return longest;//one of the longest if the set has abc, def, ghi then any one will be returned
    }


 }
```

------JUnit test case methods---------

```
    @Test
    public void testAllPossibleSubStrings () {
        Map<String,String[]> d = new LinkedHashMap(); //data
        d.put("a", new String[]{"a"});
        d.put("aa", new String[]{"a","aa"});
        d.put("ab", new String[]{"a","b","ab"});
        d.put("abc", new String[]{"a","ab","abc","b","bc"});
        d.put("abcd", new String[]{"a","ab","abc","abcd","b","bc","bcd","c","cd"});

        d.keySet().forEach(k-> {
            MyStrings s = new MyStrings(k); 
            Set<String> allSubStrings = s.getAllSubStrings();
            //System.out.println(k+"->"+allSubStrings);
            assertTrue(allSubStrings.containsAll(Arrays.asList(d.get(k))));
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void longestPalindromeSubstring() {
        System.out.println("largestPalindromeSubstring");
        Map<String,Integer> d = new LinkedHashMap(); //data
        d.put("a", 1);
        d.put("ab", 1);
        d.put("abc", 1);
        d.put("abcc", 2);
        d.put("abcdcb", 5);//"bcdcb");
        d.put("abcbabcd",5);
        d.put("abc-cbad-dabc-aa",11);

        d.keySet().forEach(k-> {
            System.out.println("==========="+k+"===================");
            MyStrings s = new MyStrings(k);
            boolean excludeOriginal = false;            
            String longestPalin = s.getLongestPalindromeSubstr(excludeOriginal);
            System.out.println("biggestPalinSubstr("+k+")="+longestPalin);
            assertEquals(longestPalin.length(),(int)d.get(k));
        });     
    }

    @Test
    public void longestNonPalindromeSubString() {
        System.out.println("getLongestNonPalindromeSubString");
        Map<String,Integer> d = new LinkedHashMap(); //data
        d.put("a", 0);
        d.put("ab", 2);
        d.put("abc", 3);
        d.put("abcc", 4);
        d.put("abcdcb", 6);//"bcdcb");
        d.put("abcbabcd",8);
        d.put("abc-cbad-dabc-aa",16);

        d.keySet().forEach(k-> {
            System.out.println("==========="+k+"===================");
            MyStrings s = new MyStrings(k); 
            boolean excludeOriginal = false;
            String longestNonPalin = s.getLongestNonPalindromeSubstr(excludeOriginal);
            System.out.println("longestNonPalin ("+k+")="+longestNonPalin );
            assertEquals(longestNonPalin.length(),(int)d.get(k));
        });     
    }
    @Test
    public void longestNonPalindromeSubString2() {
        System.out.println("getLongestNonPalindromeSubString");
        Map<String,Integer> d = new LinkedHashMap(); //data
        d.put("a", 0);
        d.put("ab", 0); //a,b are palindromes ab is excluded return
        d.put("abc", 2); //a,b,c,abc are excluded
        d.put("abcc", 3);
        d.put("abcdcb", 5);//"bcdcb");
        d.put("abcbabcd",7);
        d.put("abc-cbad-dabc-aa",15);

        d.keySet().forEach(k-> {
            System.out.println("==========="+k+"===================");
            MyStrings s = new MyStrings(k); 
            boolean excludeOriginal = true;
            String longestNonPalin = s.getLongestNonPalindromeSubstr(excludeOriginal);
            System.out.println("longestNonPalin2 ("+k+")="+longestNonPalin );
            assertEquals((int)d.get(k),longestNonPalin.length());
        });     
    }
```

Comment: I like the idea of adding a JUnit test, but these tests are way too big and print too much to stdout --- who's supposed to read that in *automated* testing?

Comment: Generally speaking, your code looks good, but needs some cleanup (commented blocks, unneeded constructor `super` call), noisy `//data` comments, ...)

Comment: but the code is not meant to be copy pasted into production. it's just to show the algorithm i used and show the output against different test cases.

Comment: I agree with that Robert. It is hard to understand. I have rectified my code and I think this should be the answer. Suggest any further optimizations. @ManasMarthi.

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine to me.

```
import java.util.*;
public class StackOverFlow{
  public static void main(String ar[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = input.next();
    int length = 0;
    for(int i = 1 ;i <= s.length() ; i++){
       if(!(s.substring(0,i).equals(new StringBuilder(s.substring(0,i)).reverse().toString()))){
        length = s.substring(0,i).length();
       }
    }   
    System.out.println(length);
  }
}
```

Comment: getting time limit exceeded in this one. @ManasMarthi any suggestions ?